# Extend RedisEngine in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I have some custom methods created in Cake's RedisEngine file to do things like Redis `spop`...etc. I know that editing the actual RedisEngine file itself within the Cake Lib is not ideal, but am unsure exactly how to extend it so that I can add my own methods. Or more specifically, if I do extend it, how to I tell Cake to use `MyRedisEngine` instead of the default one?

Comment: Like this: **https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#creating-a-storage-engine-for-cache**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [this page in the CakePHP Book](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#creating-a-storage-engine-for-cache), you can extend [CacheEngine](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#CacheEngine) by specifying the config like this in `Config/bootstrap.php`:

```
Cache::config('custom', array(
    'engine' => 'MyCustomCacheEngine', // if this doesn't work, try without the 'Engine'
    // ...
));
```

and adding a `MyCustomCacheEngine.php` file in the `app/Lib/Cache/Engine/` directory.

Comment: (thanks for pointing me to the spot in the book I missed, @ndm)